# Is there a way to subtract an array from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

How is it possible to make the output look like this?

```
list3 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

```
list3[i] = list1[i] - list2[i];
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me because the two arrays are not same length.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Infinity {

    public static int[] InitialiseStudents(int[] students) {

        for (int i = 0; i<students.length; i++){
            students[i] = i+1;
        }
        return students;
    }

    public static int[] AssignJobs (int[] NumberStudents) {
        int StudCount = NumberStudents.length;
        int[] Array = NumberStudents;

        //loop for every day(t), starting at the second day
        for (int t = 2; t <= StudCount; t++) {
            System.out.println("Tag" + t);


            int[] copy = new int[5];

            for (int i = t-1, j=0; j < 5; i+=t) {
                    copy[j++] = Array[i];
            }
            System.out.println("-------------");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy));
            System.out.println("_________");
            break;
        }
        return Array;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Students: ");
        //int n = scan.nextInt();
        int n = 10;

        int[] students = new int[n];

        InitialiseStudents(students);

        students = AssignJobs(students);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));

    }
}
```

To make to task VERY clear I just show you everything I have done and the context. This is my homework which I am curently working. The task is...

Initially, a numbering 1, 2, 3, 4, . . . of the students is determined. Then it will be that
every second (start counting with the first student) becomes Garbage officer (these are
the students with the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8, . . . ), from the rest (students 1, 3,
5, 7, . . . ) every third person becomes a refrigerator representative (these are students 5, 11, 17,
23, . . . ), of the rest (students 1, 3, 7, 9, . . . ) every fourth . . . , from which then
we can think of something for each k-th and from the rest for
every (k+1)-th etc. Apparently, some of the residents (students 1, 3, 7)
omitted during distribution and do not have to complete any of the tasks that arise.
Numbers of these students are called Omitted Numbers.
Program an application OmittedNumbers that exactly the Omitted Numbers
an area 1; : : : ;N retrieves and prints, where N is passed on the command line
will. Only use methods that are iterative.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't use the subtraction operator on arrays. Use `Set` and `Set.removeAll` instead.

Comment: @StephenC it looks like a set difference to me -- otherwise wouldn't the result be [-1, -2, -3, ... ?

Comment: @StephenC According to the result, the OP wants a set-theoretical difference between the two arrays.

Comment: Although according to their code they do want vector subtraction...

Comment: Yea ... it looks like they have misunderstood the problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: OP - Please describe in words what >you< mean by "subtract an array from an array".

Comment: Well I have deleted the for loop to avoid, confusion :/ ... I just want to delete the elements of list2 in list1 so that it become that list3

Comment: With subtract I meant delete

Comment: Are they ordered consistently?

Comment: Is `list2` a subset of `list1`?

Comment: The list1 starts at 1 and ends with 10.  So yeah kinda, And list 2 is just every second number

Comment: I can see that. I'm asking if it's guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution # 1

Convert your arrays to list

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2);
```

For List, you can use `removeAll` function

```
list1.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println(list1)
```

#### Solution # 2

Traverse through each index and remove items if same as follow

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int[] array2 = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            result.add(array1[i]);
        }
    }
}

// convert list to array (if needed)
Integer[] resultArray = result.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

record ChoiceResult(List<Integer> chosen, List<Integer> remainder) {}

public class Choose {
    static ChoiceResult choose(int interval, List<Integer> candidates) {
        List<Integer> chosen = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> remainder = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); i++) {
            if ((i+1) % interval == 0) {
                chosen.add(candidates.get(i));
            } else {
                remainder.add(candidates.get(i));
            }
        }
        return new ChoiceResult(chosen, remainder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> students = List.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
        ChoiceResult garbage = choose(2, students);
        ChoiceResult fridge = choose(3, garbage.remainder());
        System.out.println("Garbage: " + garbage.chosen());
        System.out.println("Fridge: " + fridge.chosen());
    }
}
```

It has the feature of working with an immutable `List` for the input to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double-layer for loop filtering,The following is just a sample code, you need to think about the details(For example, how to improve the efficiency of calculation, because the efficiency of double-layer for loop is very low).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] arr2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    List<Integer> rt = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == false) {
            rt.add(arr1[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(rt);

    Integer[] finalArr = rt.toArray(new Integer[rt.size()]);

    for (int i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(finalArr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection framework supports union/intersection at base level and just utilize it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 10));
        list1.removeAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
}
```

Using Stream API:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
        List<Integer> list2 = List.of(2, 4, 6, 8, 10);
        List<Integer> list3 = list1.stream()
                .filter(i -> !list2.contains(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list3);
    }
}
```

[collection methods reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)